# identifier of an instance of ManagerEntity was altered

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-one

As per my requirement, I have created ManyToOne relationship using JPA between Customer and Manager

```
class CustomerEntity{

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "manager_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private ManagerEntity manager;

}

class ManagerEntity{

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "manager", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private List<CustomerEntity> customerlist;

 }
```

Now, I am trying to update/reassign Manager to Customer using below code

```
public void updateManager(Customer customer) throws Exception {
    CustomerEntity customerEntity = customerDao.find(customer.getId());
    ManagerEntity managerEntity = userDao.find(customer.getManagerId()); 
    customerEntity.setManager(managerEntity);
    getSession().update(entity);
}
```

But while saving I am getting exception mentioned below

*Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of ManagerEntity was altered from 10 to 15*

As per exception, I can understand that it's trying to update row in ManagerEntity i.e. child table but I do not want any update in ManagerEntity, Only any existing ManagerEntity should be reassigned to CustomerEntity.

I tried to provide CascadeType.MERGE or CascadeType.DETACH in CustomerEntity but it did not work.

Can anyone suggest me correct way to update CustomerEntity entity i.e. Parent  without updating ManagerEntity i.e. Child Entity

Comment: Why don´t you do **customerEntity.getManager().setName("new name")** your customer should have the manager, so you don´t have to retrieved from DB. It seems to me that the manager entity you are updating is not the same that the customer has and hibernate complains

Comment: why you want to fetch ManagerEntity separately? when you fetch CustomerEntity it should fetch Manager as well. Hence no need to set manager in customer entity. Change fetch type to eager and see if your code fetching manager along with customer or not.

Comment: it looks correct unless you're doing something strange in the .setManager method, can you show the code?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to do a save update cascade

1. Associate your child as save-update cascade
2. Fetch the parent
3. Update the child entity
4. Do a saveOrUpdate

Ref : -http://javaforloop.com/hibernate/hibernate-cascade-inverse-example-none-save-update-delete-delete-orphan/

I would suggest you to pass the id of manager to be updated as  a separate argument

```
public void updateManager(Customer customer , Long managerId) throws Exception {

//Below code will fetch the customer you need to update
    CustomerEntity customerEntity = customerDao.find(customer.getId());
    ManagerEntity managerEntity = new ManagerEntity();
    managerEntity.setId(managerId);
    customerEntity.setManager(managerEntity);
    getSession().saveOrUpdate(customerEntity);
}
```

Comment: I tried to evict managerEntity using

getSession().evict(managerEntity);

It saves CustomerEntity but ManagerEntity is not saved which is obvious. Can you please suggest way to save manager entity?

Comment: I don't det it you wanted to update customer and not manager. If you want to update child entity you need to cascade it.

Comment: I am sorry Saket. I mistyped question. I do not want to save ManagerEntity at all. Can you please suggest on Not updating child while updating parent, I do not want to update child entity.
Once again sorry for my wrong comment above.

Comment: So you want to update the customer but with what information? Can you please elaborate.?

Comment: Saket You got it.It's Customer Edit functionality, By default Customer has some information like name or any other personal information also has default manager assigned to it, Now while edit any existing manager can be assigned to a customer. As I mentioned in my question, CustomerEntity (which represents customer_tbl in my DB) has ManagerEntity (which represents manager_tbl in my DB ) it has created foreign key manager_id in customer_tbl. I need to update manager_id column in my customer_tbl.
Please refer relationship structure mentioned in the question. Hope, I'm able to clarify correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I made a little test and got the same exception with this code:

```
void setManager(ManagerEntity managerEntity) {
    this.manager.setId(managerEntity.getId());
}
```

instead of the right one:

```
void setManager(ManagerEntity managerEntity) {
    this.manager = managerEntity;
}
```